# Confused On Colors Xterm Vs Zsh - How to set Xterm without breaking Zsh colors?

Tags: terminal, zsh, colors, xterm, rxvt

I am confused by the color settings for xterm (or uxvt in my case but uses the same) verus the zsh PROMPT colors.

If I change the xterm colors then it changes the zsh prompt colors and I think it makes the zsh prompt colors inaccurate.

How do I handle this situation? How do I set the xterm colors where they do break the zsh prompt colors?

Example `.Xdefaults`

```
!colors
!black
URxvt-ml*color0:                #676767
URxvt-ml*color8:                #757575
!red
URxvt-ml*color1:                #EA6868
URxvt-ml*color9:                #FF7272
!green
URxvt-ml*color2:                #ABCB8D
URxvt-ml*color10:               #AFD78A
!yellow
URxvt-ml*color3:                #E8AE5B
URxvt-ml*color11:               #FFA75D
!blue
URxvt-ml*color4:                #71C5F4
URxvt-ml*color12:               #67CDE9
!magenta
URxvt-ml*color5:                #E2BAF1
URxvt-ml*color13:               #ECAEE9
!cyan
URxvt-ml*color6:                #21F1EA
URxvt-ml*color14:               #36FFFC
!white
URxvt-ml*color7:                #F1F1F1
URxvt-ml*color15:               #FFFFFF
```

Example `PROMPT` from zsh (not using oh my zsh):

```
PROMPT='%B%F{046}%n%B%F{123}@%B%F{046}%m %F{051}%b%F{015}%(4~|...|)%3~%B%F{239}$(__git_ps1)%f%k
%F{123}%#%f%b '
```

Answer (score 0):

[image: screenshot]

I don't see a difference with regards to the zsh prompt you gave with and without the resource settings you gave.

Those only change colours 0 to 15. And indeed with `%F{green}` which uses colour 2, I see a difference (and for me your changes make it less visible on a white background), but your `$PROMPT` mostly uses palette colours above 15. Those above 15 are meant to give you wide selection with all possible shades (but with coarse granularity as there are only just over 200 ones) and are generally consistent from one terminal to the next.

Those you don't want to change and are the ones you want to use if you don't want to be affected by customisations made to 0-15 ANSI colours.

See also the [`zsh/nearcolor`](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Zsh-Modules.html#The-zsh_002fnearcolor-Module) module in `zsh` for terminals that don't support true colour escape sequences to still be able to use RGB specifications and let zsh pick the closest colour from the palette.

So for instance:

```
print -P '%F{#ABCB8D}text%f'
```

(same in `$PROMPT`) would print the text in that `#ABCB8D` RGB specification on terminals that support the true-colour escape sequences like xterm/vte... (something like `\033[38;2;171;203;141m`), and on those that don't but support a 88 or 256 colour palette like `rxvt`:

```
zmodload zsh/nearcolor
print -P '%F{#ABCB8D}text%f'
```

Would pick the nearest colour from the palette (here 150, with the `\e[38;5;150m` escape sequence as for `%F{150}`).